# WordPress 404 Images - Images not found after deleted from media

Tags: images, errors, 404-error, links, customization

I am trying to develop the website to find images that have been deleted from the media library as they were not needed.

These Images that I have deleted have previously been on pages but have been replaced on the page now... but if you go to https://tools.pingdom.com/#!/ctzBfY/http://waggypetservices.co.uk you can see that some of the deleted images are still being called... this call also be seen in the page source.

My question is how can I find what is calling these images and stop it from calling the deleted images?

I have cleared my cache etc already and re-save permalinks.

```
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs bottom-xs flexbox image-group-bottom-3-img space-bottom-xs center-xs"><img class="left-img shadow-large-black" data-size="500x300" src="http://waggypetservices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-dog_in_garden.jpg" /> <img class="center-img shadow-large-black" data-size="500x300" src="http://waggypetservices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-sleeping-golden-retrevier.jpg" /> <img class="right-img shadow-large-black" data-size="500x300" src="http://waggypetservices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/cropped-dog_walking_3-1.jpg" /></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="content-12" style="background-color: #f5fafd;" data-label="Content" data-id="content-2" data-export-id="content-2" data-category="content" class="content-2 content-section content-section-spacing">
<div>
<div class="row middle-xs">
<div class="col-sm-5 bg-image shadow-large-black" data-bg="image" style="background-image: url('http://waggypetservices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/dog-walking-image.jpg');"></div>
<div class="col-sm-7 full-col-left-padding full-col-right-padding">
<div class="row">
<div data-type="column" class="space-bottom-small content-title-col">
<h2 class="">Dog Walking Chesterfield</h2>
<p class="">Waggy Walks Chesterfield offer private walks for pooches who prefer their own company as well as group walks for more sociable dogs.
At Waggy Walks we understand that every pet has different exercise requirements. These can vary significantly between individual animals and we know that every pet is unique and special. In fact, every animal is exceptional.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are getting called in the Open Graph (OG) tags. Please check any plugin that is generating those or remove them if they are hard-coded.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which plugin this could be?

Comment: The one which is related to on-page SEO. See if you can sort it out. Send me a list of plugins. I will try as well

Comment: better-font-awesome, borlabs-cahce, broken-link-checker, child-theme-configurator, contact-form-7, duplicator, elementor, mesmerize-companion, redirection, siteorigin-panels, so-widgets-bundle, tablepress, updraftplus, wordpress-seo (yoast), wp-smushit...... I have tried disabling yoast SEO and clearing cache which did not help

Comment: I have just renamed the plugins folder to plugins.old and the issue is still there... so it cant be a plugin causing the issue?

Comment: Please see my question, I have added the code that looks like it is referring it from the page text... what sections should i remove to just get rid of the image link